# PHP, Ruby, Python...Yuma?

Tags: web-services, realbasic

In considering languages to use in creating a web-application that interfaces with a database back-end, has anyone had experience in using Yuma and can share how stable it is and what kind of performance it may give?

Comment: Don't really have an answer, but why is there a realbasic tag?

Comment: @dex Because Yuma is a Web environment provided by RealBASIC.

Comment: Yuma is a way to utilize REALbasic syntax within HTML, much like how PHP works.  It is a 3rd party product and is not affiliated with REAL Software.

Comment: I take it that not many StackOverflow-ers are using Yuma then :-)

Comment: I'd be surprised if many here are using RB. The RB forums is a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Yuma and am pretty happy with it. However, I haven't thrown the kitchen sink at it so don't know how well it scales. Yuma does provide a developer download so if you're interested you should check it out. I use it for a few apps that have a custom back ends. 
If you're familiar with RealBasic it's a piece of cake to use.

The only downside is there are tons of source for php and python (scripts, etc), publicly available source for Yuma is practically non-existent because it is so new. Also, finding a hosting provider to host a Yuma back-end is doable but probably not as prevalent as php.

I'd recommend trying it out if you're a RealBasic user. Very little learning curve and some good stuff like caching and use of FASTCGI, etc.